# SP.Web.EnsureUser(user) does not seem to work. (JavaScript Client OM)

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Supposedly, `SP.Web.ensureUser(user)` works according to [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj245233.aspx) but I cannot seem to get it to work in my JS code.

While debugging, I can see that `SP.Web` exists and the user variable is populated with the user that I expect.  However I get the following exception:

```
Object function (b,a){ULSdih:;SP.Web.initializeBase(this,[b,a])} has no method 'ensureUser'
```

[image: Watching SP.Web.ensureUser() fail.]

Comment: Hi! Can you provide some code example how you do invoke this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to call the `ensureUser` method against a valid `web` object. The following code should work:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var theUser = context.get_web().ensureUser("DEV\testowner");
context.load(theUser);

context.executeQueryAsync(function(){

 alert(theUser.get_title());

},
function(sender, args){

  alert(args.get_message());

});
```