# Not able find user in userinformation list

Tags: development, user-profile, people-search

I am using one list and it has one person field configured for "All Users".

So when i type some email ID in that person field, it is getting user and it works well.

But when i wants to add new record through client object model, some users are not available in UserinformationList in c# and Javascript as well.

Here is the code which i am trying to get all users list.

```
 ClientContext clientContext1 = new ClientContext(SiteUrl);
 clientContext1.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
 UserCollection usrdd = clientContext1.Web.SiteUsers;
 clientContext1.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: users are added to UserinformationList on their first login to site. so if user are never login, you cant find it in userinformationlist.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get a reference to user object (either an existing one, or one that is just being created), use the ensureUser method (source [from this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58162/sp-web-ensureuseruser-does-not-seem-to-work-javascript-client-om)):

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var theUser = context.get_web().ensureUser("DEV\testowner");
context.load(theUser);

context.executeQueryAsync(function(){

 alert(theUser.get_title());

},
function(sender, args){

  alert(args.get_message());

});
```